# How to solve this second order nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

i have to solve following differential equation in coupled heat transfer
$$ka\frac 1r\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dT}{dr}\right)-\epsilon\sigma T^4=0$$
where, $k$ (conductivity), $a$ (thickness),  and emissivity $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$ are all constant. T varies with $r$

With boundary conditions: $T=T_i$ at $r=r_i$, and $\frac{dT}{dr}=0$ at $r=r_o$

**My attempt:** I assumed two new variables and two new constants to simplify DE

i assume $$\theta=\frac{T}{T_i}, \ R=\frac{r-r_i}{r_o-r_i}, \text{&} \ \delta=\frac{r_o}{r_i}, \ \gamma=\frac{(r_o-r_i)^2\epsilon\sigma T_i^3}{ka}$$

after substitution, I simplified differential equation as
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dR^2}+\frac{1}{R+\frac{1}{\delta-1}}\frac{d\theta}{dR}-\gamma \theta^4=0$$
where $\theta$ and $R$ are new variables and new boundary conditions are

$\theta=1$ at $R=0$ and $\frac{d\theta}{dR}=0$ at $R=1$

I know how to solve second order linear D.E. but above D.E. is a second order non-linear differential equation which I don't know how to solve because it has non linear $\theta^4$ term ?

please help me solve this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$ka\frac{d^2T}{dr^2}+\frac{ka}{r}\frac{dT}{dr}-\epsilon\sigma (T(r))^4=0$$
As far as I know there is no standard function available to express the solution of this non-linear ODE.

One could try to find approximate solution on the form of finite series. More likely in practice one use numerical methods of solving.

Nevertheless the ODE can be simplified thanks to the change of function
$$T(r)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{ka}{\epsilon\sigma}}\:u(r)$$
which leads to :
$$\boxed{\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{du}{dr}- (u(r))^4=0}$$
There is no parameter in the transformed ODE.

The boundary conditions are :
$$u_1=u(r_1)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\epsilon\sigma}{ka}}\:T(r_1)\quad\text{and}\quad u'(r_0)=0$$